# How to implement 16bit stereo mixing on ARMv6+?

Tags: c, audio, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I need to optimize my mixing code in c for faster response time, so i decided to use inline assembly to do a mixing of two buffers into a new bigger buffer. Basically i have left and right channels separated and i want to put them together into a buffer. So i need to put 2 bytes from the left channel and then two bytes from the right channel and so on.
for this i decided to send my 3 pointers to my assembly code where i intend to copy memory pointed by the left channel pointer into R0 register and memory pointed by right channel pointer into R1 afterwards i intend to mix R0 and R1 into R3 and R4 to later save those registers to memory.(I intend to use other free registers to do same procedure and reduce processing time with pipelining)

So I have two registers R0 and R1 with data, and need to mix them into R3 and R4, and i need to end up is R3 = R0HI(high-part) + R1HI(high-part) and R4 = R0LO(low-part) + R1LO(low-part)

I can think of using a bitwise shifts, but my questions is if there is an easier way to do it like in intel x86 architecture where you could transfer the data into ax register and then us ah as high part and al as low part?

is my thinking right? is there a faster way to do this?

my actual (not working) code in the ndk

```
void mux(short *pLeftBuf, short *pRightBuf, short *pOutBuf, int vecsamps_stereo) {
    int iterations = vecsamps_stereo / 4;
    asm volatile(
        "ldr r0, %[outbuf];"
        "ldr r1, %[leftbuf];"
        "ldr r2, %[rightbuf];"
        "ldr r3, %[iter];"

        "ldr r4, [r3];"
        "mov r8, r4;"
        "mov r9, r0;"
        "mov r4, #0;"
        "mov r10, r4;"

        "loop:; "

        "ldr r2, [r1];"
        "ldr r3, [r2];"

        "ldr r7, =0xffff;"

        "mov r4, r2;"
        "and r4, r4, r7;"
        "mov r5, r3;"
        "and r5, r5, r7;"
        "lsl r5, r5, #16;"
        "orr r4, r4, r5;"

        "lsl r7, r7, #16;"

        "mov r5, r2;"
        "and r5, r5, r7;"
        "mov r6, r3;"
        "and r6, r6, r7;"
        "lsr r6, r6, #16;"
        "orr r5, r5, r6;"

        "mov r6, r9;"
        "str r4, [r6];"
        "add r6, r6, #1;"
        "str r5, [r6];"
        "add r6, r6, #1;"
        "mov r9, r6;"

        "mov r4, r10;"
        "add r4, r4, #1;"
        "mov r10, r4;"
        "cmp r4, r8;"
        "blt loop"

        :[outbuf] "=m" (pOutBuf)
        :[leftbuf] "m" (pLeftBuf) ,[rightbuf] "m" (pRightBuf),[iter] "m" (pIter)
        :"r0","r1","r2","r3","memory"
    );
}
```

Comment: Before considering assembler, you should examine the performance of the existing C implementation for performance - most likely by profiling it.  Posting your code here would be helpful - as would knowing precisely which ARM device you are using?  Does it have NEON?

Comment: Could you clarify if you mean pairwise 16 + 16 to 32-bit addition or just interleaving? The packed add instructions I mentioned may not be relevant but the rest is either way.

Comment: http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/neon.php

Comment: @marko i am doing signal processing in separate channels, using fft eq and before that compression and few other things, the timing is not bad at all but i found a bottle neck in this part.

Comment: @Notlikethat i mean pairwise 16 + 16-bit addition and my target are arm processors with and without neon, next optimization will be compiling for neon devices using its advantages.

Comment: @artless noise i am targeting android and ios devices

Comment: The [armv6 SIMD](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/dsp-simd.php) (as per *Notlikethat*) is your lowest common denominator for the *best/fastest* technology.  If you were to implement a [**soft modem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmodem) the amount of 16bit DSP code would be more critical.  For simply mux/demux of streams, the pure ARM is probably sufficient for most AUDIO rates as per *RJP*.  Also, the amount of armv6 CPUs maybe small and your majority will support *NEON* as per auslen; with the common paradox that the faster CPUs supports the faster ISA.

Comment: `vqadd_u16` or `vqadd_s16` (4samples/2 stereo per operation) are the best NEON instructions. [`QADD`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihidceh.html) for CPUs without NEON needs an operation for each sample (4 operations), plus the shifting/aggregation before storing.

Comment: @artlessnoise you told me just what i needed to know :) found some useful coding [here](http://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/doc/group__groupDSPs.html)

Answer (score 1):

ARM registers are strictly 32-bit, however provided you're on a recent enough core (v6+, but not Thumb-only v7-M) there are a number of suitable instructions for dealing with halfwords [(`PKHBT`, `PKHTB`)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihjedjg.html), or arbitrary slices of registers (`BFI`, `UBFX`), not to mention crazy parallel add/subtract instructions that frighten me (available with saturating arithmetic which can be useful for audio, too)..

However, if your machine implements NEON instructions they would be the route to the optimal implementation since this is *exactly* the sort of thing they're designed for. Plus, they should be accessible through compiler intrinsics so you can use them directly in C code.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be 100% clear on what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want:

```
    R3[31:16] = R0[31:16], R3[15:0] = R1[31:16];
    R4[31:16] = R0[15:0], R4[15:0] = R1[15:0];
```

and not the actual sum.

In this case, you should be able to accomplish this relatively efficiently with a spare register for a 16-bit mask. ARM assembly offers shifting of a second operand as a part of most arithmetic or logical instructions.

```
    MOV R2, 0xffff               ; load 16-bit mask into lower half of R2

    AND R3, R2, R1, LSR #16      ; R3 = R2 & (R1 >> 16), or R3[15:0] = R1[31:16]
    ORR R3, R3, R0, LSR #16      ; R3 = R3 | (R0 >> 16), or R3[31:16] = R0[31:16]

    AND R4, R2, R1               ; R4 = R2 & R1, or R4[15:0] = R1[15:0]
    ORR R4, R4, R0, LSL #16      ; R4 = R4 | (R1 << 16), or R4[31:16] = R0[15:0]

    ; repeat to taste
```

Another option is to load just the 16 bits at a time, but this may be lower performance if your buffers are in slow memory, and it may not work at all if it doesn't support access less than 32 bits. I'm not certain if the core will request the 32 bits and mask out what isn't needed or if it relies on the memory to handle the byte lanes.

```
    ; assume R2 contains CH1 pointer, R3 contains CH2 pointer,
    ; and R1 contains output ptr
    LDRH R0, [R2]                ; load first 16 bits pointed to by CH1 into R0
    STRH R0, [R1]                ; store those 16 bites back into *output
    LDRH R0, [R3]                ; load first 16 bits pointed to by CH2 into R0
    STRH R0, [R1, #2]!           ; store those 16 bites back into *(output+2),
                                 ; write output+2 to R1

    ; after "priming" we can now run the following for
    ; auto increment of pointers.
    LDRH R0, [R2, #2]!           ; R0 = *(CH1+2), CH1 += 2
    STRH R0, [R1, #2]!           ; *(Out+2) = R0, Out += 2
    LDRH R0, [R3, #2]!           ; R0 = *(CH2+2), CH1 += 2
    STRH R0, [R1, #2]!           ; *(Out+2) = R0, Out += 2

    ; Lather, rinse, repeat.
```

These two examples make use of some of the handy features of ARM assembly. The first example makes use of the built in shift available on most instructions, while the second makes use of sized load/store instructions as well as the write-back on these instructions. These should both be compatible with Cortex-M cores. If you do have a more advanced ARM, @Notlikethat's answer is more suitable.

In terms of code size, when you add the load and store to the first example, you end up executing two load instructions, the four logic instructions, and two stores for a total of eight instructions for mixing two samples. The second examples uses two loads and two stores for a total of four instructions when mixing one sample, or, well, eight instructions for mixing two.

You will probably find the first example works faster, as it has fewer memory accesses, and the number of stores can be reduced by using a `STM` store multiple instruction (ie `STMIA OutputRegister!, {R3, R4}`). In fact, the first example can be pipelined a bit by using eight registers. `LDMIA` can be used to load four 16 bit samples from a channel in one instruction, perform two sets of the four mixing instructions, and then store the four output registers in one `STMIA` instruction. This likely wouldn't offer much benefit in performance since it will likely interact with the memory in the same manner (`STM` and `LDM` just execute multiple `LDR`s and `STR`s), but if you are optimizing for minimal instructions, this would result in 11 instructions to mix four samples (compared to 16).

Comment: +1 Masking is not needed as *shifts* usually pad with zero; especially your logical versions.  It the system has *cache*, then the `ldrh` versions maybe faster.  However, if this is a sound driver audio buffer, it may involve DMA and not be cached.

Comment: Good point! I'm not sure why I didn't realize that, since I counted on it with the left shift. The masking is still needed when moving the lower half of R1 into the lower half of R4, but this could be done without masking by using `UBFX` to extract those bits. `UBFX R4, R1, #0, #16`, but this is Thumb-2 specific. Although, the 16-bit immediate `MOV` I have looks to be a Thumb-2 thing, as well.

Comment: @artlessnoise `lsr` shifts in zeros, whereas `asr` is sign-preserving, so it shifts in copies of bit 31.

Comment: @RJP I've tried to implement the first code, but i wasn't able to understand what it does, for what i see it erases the low part of r1 since with lsr #16 in when saving to r3. At least thats what i understand if i'm wrong please correct me. On the other hand,
i wrote my own inline assembly code and tried unsuccessfully to implement it in the ndk.
i added my code to the question

Comment: @alexm, I am fairly certain that when a shift is applied as part of the flexible operand, it doesn't write back to the source register and is only applied as an input. For example, `mov R1, R0, LSR #16` will put the upper 16 bits of `R0` into `R1` without modifying the value in `R0`. ARM lacks actual shift instructions. The ARM instruction set quick reference I have cite the instruction for `LSR{S} Rd, Rm, <shift>` as being identical to `MOV{S} Rd, Rm, LSR <shift>`